# Android Facebook share issue?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using android-facebook sdk to share to facebook. Sharing works fine. But, i don't need the caption in the feed to share. If i leave caption in json, it stil shows some arbitrary String. How can i solve it?.

Code i used to share.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("picture", imageUrl);
b.putString("message", imageDesc);
b.putString("description","Hai" );
b.putString("name","Show us something Beautiful");
b.putString("link",bitly);
```

If i give any caption it shows. The code with caption is

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("picture", imageUrl);
b.putString("caption", "image");
b.putString("message", imageDesc);
b.putString("description","Hai" );
b.putString("name","Show us something Beautiful");
b.putString("link",bitly);
```

**How can i remove caption?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put 'picture' and 'message' in the bundle...